# Cannot connect to mySQL server on microsoft azure in processing

Tags: java, mysql, database, azure, processing

I am attempting to connect to my MySQL server hosted in the Azure cloud through the processing IDE, however, it will not let me connect. below is the code.

```
 import de.bezier.data.sql.*;
import processing.serial.*;

Serial myPort;  // Create object from Serial class
String val;     // Data received from the serial port
MySQL msql;      //Create MySQL Object

void setup()
{

  String password = "pass";
  String username="";
  String url ="jdbc:mysql://oursystem.mysql.database.azure.com:3306/projectdb?verifyServerCertificate=true&useSSL=true&requireSSL=false"; 
  msql = new MySQL(this,url,"projectdb",username,password);

  if ( msql.connect() )
    {
        println("connected");
    }
    else
    {
        // connection failed !
    }
}
```

Once i run this i get the error

```
SQL.connect(): Could not connect to the database ( jdbc:mysql://jdbc:mysql://oursystem.mysql.database.azure.com:3306/projectdb?verifyServerCertificate=true&useSSL=true&requireSSL=false/projectdb ).

java.sql.SQLException: The connection property 'requireSSL' only accepts values of the form: 'true', 'false', 'yes' or 'no'. The value 'false/projectdb' is not in this set.
```

if i were to connect to a local host MYSQL server it would connect fine, Any ideas?

Comment: Why does the URL in your error contain two `jdbc:mysql` parts?

Comment: I have no clue, I've been trying to figure that out

Comment: What happens if you get rid of that part in your String?

Comment: it gives the error - SQL.connect(): Could not connect to the database ( jdbc:mysql://oursystem.mysql.database.azure.com:3306/projectdb?verifyServerCertificate=true&useSSL=true/projectdb ).

java.sql.SQLException: The connection property 'useSSL' only accepts values of the form: 'true', 'false', 'yes' or 'no'. The value 'true/projectdb' is not in this set.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct driver `.jar` version?

Comment: I believe that I am, I am kind of a newbie to the processing IDE, I imported the only sqlib library that there was and to my knowledge that there is for this IDE so I assume that I am using the correct jar file. is there a way to check for certain? I don't see any option to check like properties etc...

Comment: I'd check inside the library to see which version you're using, then check the documentation for your database to see which version it needs. Make sure they're the same.

Comment: so I have checked the site for the download of the previous version of this library -> http://bezier.de/processing/libs/sql/ and I have looked in the folder and that version used a very old connector for MySQL. The processing IDE lets you import a library directly from within the IDE, much like NetBeans lets you install extensions. I installed what is apparently the latest version of this sql lib which is 3.0. it is still not letting me connect with this. I think i will just use python to do the job instead, this is making me tear my hair out